# hpux 11.31 : what is the difference between distribuited volume and stripe lvm?

Tags: lvm, hp-ux

With this command

```
lvcreate -D
```

I create a distribuited lvm.

With this  I create a striped lvm.

```
lvcreate -L 1220 -i 3 -I 64 -n name /dev/vg02
```

What is the difference between a striped and distributed volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributed works at physical extent level. With

`lvcreate -D y`

Each new extent is created in a different disk that the previous one, if possible.

With stripes, every extent is distributed across x physical disks, with the stripe size specified with -I, being x specified by -i. Stripe size has to be less or equal than extent size.

The final result can be similar, but the concept and control you have on it are different.